# Show help text when command encounters error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a working command. I want to add some options to it. None of these options are technically required, but *at least* and *at most* 1 of them needs to be supplied for any single invocation of the command.  I have the options set up and can detect successfully these circumstances.

However, I wish to show the help dialog for the command whenever the check fails.  If my command is `my:command`, I want the output of running `$ php artisan my:command -h` to display after my error message.

I have tried doing this:

```
$this->error('my error message');

// Causes infinite failness since it is calling the command but not passing 
// options (or ignoring it), thus hitting the same error condition
$this->call('my:command', ['-h' => true]); 

// Causes.. nothing. No error, no blank line, I just see my error message
Artisan::call('help', ['command_name' => 'my:command', 'format' => 'txt']);

// Both of these also cause nothing to be displayed. They are from:
// Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command
echo $this->getHelp();
echo $this->getProcessedHelp();
```

Is there a way to get the same formatted help text of a command or trigger the help message to display when an error like this is encountered?

Update

The default output for a command when running `$ php artisan help my:command` is something like this:

```
Usage:
my:command [options] [--] [<argument>]

Options:
  -h, --help             Display this help message
  -q, --quiet            Do not output any message
  -V, --version          Display this application version
      --ansi             Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi          Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction   Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]        The environment the command should run under.
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose   Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

I want to output this after my error message.

Comment: can you give a example of what you want, i mean what you want to show on console after running the command

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen I have updated it with the output of running `php artisan help my:command`.  That's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show help message after your error add this after your error message line

```
$this->call('help', ['command_name' => 'test:mycommand', 'format' => 'raw']);
```